# Outlook Reminders Created in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, javascript, calendar, outlook

Not sure if this possible.  I want to create reminders but I don't have access to SharePoint Designer to create a workflow.  Is there a way to add an item to a list and it automatically create a reminder in outlook? Or that it creates a calendar event that can be a reminder?

Comment: do you have access to visual studio?

Comment: @Danilo Not at the moment but I can get it.  Do you have a VS solution? Thanks

Comment: yes, I had same request. Basically what you should look for is how to edit ICS file and import information in it from SharePoint calendar list to Outlook.